# Java - ZonedDateTime does not correctly convert to Date object?

Tags: java, date, time, java-8, zoneddatetime

I have the following Java code:

```
Date convertedDate = Date.from(zonedDateTime.toInstant());
```

The Issue I am having is that `convertedDate`is not correct in comparison to the zonedDateTime object.

For Example when I have a zonedDateTime object of:

```
2021-09-16T12:00
```

with zone:

```
Africa/Abidjan
```

The code above converts this to:

```
Thu Sep 16 13:00:00 BST 2021
```

What I would be expecting here is

```
 Thu Sep 16 10:00:00 BST 2021
```

As the `Africa/Abidjan` timezone is 2 hours ahead of BST.

How can I solve this?

Comment: "As the Africa/Abidjan timezone is 2 hours ahead of BST." <- Are you sure about that? The timezone of the Ivory coast is UTC + 0, while BST is UTC +1. So Africa/Abidjan timezone should be 1 hour behind BST which is why it adds that hour when you display time as BST.

Comment: ok so my code is correct then in this case?

Comment: It looks correct to me. 2021-09-16T12:00 in Africa/Abidjan timezone would be Thu Sep 16 13:00:00 BST 2021.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The given ZonedDateTime
        ZonedDateTime zdtAbidjan = ZonedDateTime.of(
                                        LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2021, 9, 16),
                                        LocalTime.of(12, 0)),
                                        ZoneId.of("Africa/Abidjan")
                                    );
        System.out.println(zdtAbidjan);

        ZonedDateTime zdtLondon = zdtAbidjan.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
        System.out.println(zdtLondon);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-09-16T12:00Z[Africa/Abidjan]
2021-09-16T13:00+01:00[Europe/London]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/tl9gmQ)

- The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).
- From the output, it is clear that 2021-09-16T12:00Z[Africa/Abidjan] is equal to 2021-09-16T13:00+01:00[Europe/London].

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 3):

[Answer by Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68446002/642706) is correct. Here are a few more thoughts.

## Time zone names

`BST` is not a [real time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Perhaps you meant `Europe/London`. And that is *not* GMT/UTC. The London time zone can vary in its offset, because of [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) and perhaps other reasons.

## UTC

Let's look at your moment in each of the three different time zones.

First we parse your input as a `LocalDateTime`, lacking the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. Then we assign a time zone for [Abidjan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abidjan) as the context to produce a `ZonedDateTime` object. We adjust to another time zone, resulting in a second `ZonedDateTime` that represents the same moment, the same point on the timeline, but a different wall-clock time. Lastly, we extract a `Instant` to effectively adjust into UTC. A `Instant` represents a moment in UTC, always in UTC.

```java
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2021-09-16T12:00" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtAbidjan = ldt.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Abidjan" ) ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtLondon = zdtAbidjan.withZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" ) ) ;
Instant instant = zdtAbidjan.toInstant() ;  // Adjust to UTC by extracting an `Instant` object.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/dECCt3).

```
ldt: 2021-09-16T12:00
zdtAbidjan: 2021-09-16T12:00Z[Africa/Abidjan]
zdtLondon: 2021-09-16T13:00+01:00[Europe/London]
instant: 2021-09-16T12:00:00Z
```

The `Z` at the end means an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds, pronounced “Zulu”. So we can zee that noon on that September day in Côte d'Ivoire is the same as in UTC, having an offset of zero. In contrast, the `+01:00` tells us that London time is an hour ahead. So the clock reads 1 PM (`13:00`) rather than noon.

## Fetch the offset

You can determine the offset in effect at a particular moment via the `ZoneRules` class. The offset info is represented by the [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) class.

```java
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Abidjan" ) ;
ZoneRules rules = z.getRules() ;
ZoneOffset offset = rules.getOffset( LocalDateTime.parse( "2021-09-16T12:00" ) ) ;
int offsetInSeconds = offset.getTotalSeconds() ;
```

Or condense that to:

```
ZoneId
.of( "Africa/Abidjan" )
.getRules()
.getOffset( LocalDateTime.parse( "2021-09-16T12:00" ) )
.getTotalSeconds()
```

When run we see again that Côte d'Ivoire is using an offset of zero at that date-time.

```
rules: ZoneRules[currentStandardOffset=Z]
offset: Z
offsetInSeconds: 0
```

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]